# File uploading in parallel chunks using jquery file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

Using `blueimp` JQuery file upload plugin.
Am able to upload a large file in sequential chunks .

But my requirement is to upload the same file in parallel chunks instead of sequential.

How can I achieve this using the above specified plugin ?

What are the changes required at server side (Currently using Servlets with Weblogic server) to handle parallel requests ?

Comment: Allowing chucks to upload simultaneously should not be rocket science. I already have the server side file handler code to deal with it. Now I'm working on modify jquery.fileupload.js to support it. It will obviously require another option and since I am new to writing jquery it will take a bit of time for me to figure it out, but alas I will. It would have been nice if the author of blueimp had posted an override method to do it. However I think if I look at the resumable override he has at [link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads) I have a feeling it mig

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the source of the [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L131) it looks like you need to make sure you use the configuration setting **limitConcurrentUploads** and use an integer greater than 0.

Comment: **limitConcurrentUploads** setting is for multiple file uploads concurrently. But my requirement is to upload the chunks of same file concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched the [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L793) code and found that next chunk will be created only after previous chunk is uploaded successfully.  That means this plugin you can't do parallel chunk uploads, only concurrent file uploads.  You have only one way overwriting the _chunkedUpload method.  The process of overwriting shold be something like this [jquery widget overwrite](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Plugin-extensions) (i am not sure).

Comment: Eng.: Parallel = Concurrent ;)

Comment: thnx for grammar fix)

Comment: Thanks @AlexNikulin for spending time on this.